# geteuid returns wrong value

Tags: linux, permissions

I have an executable with the suid bit (and the sgid bit too):

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 flag03  level03 8627 Mar  5  2016 level03*
```

`cat /etc/passwd` reveals the following id for the level03 and flag03 users:

```
level03:x:2003:2003::/home/user/level03:/bin/bash
flag03:x:3003:3003::/home/flag/flag03:/bin/bash

[...]
```

More, the executable seems to call `geteuid` and `getegid` at the beginning.

I expect `geteuid` to return `3003`, because of the suid bit, and `getegid` to return `2003`, but when I run `ltrace ./level03`, here's the output:

```
__libc_start_main(0x80484a4, 1, 0xbffff7f4, 0x8048510, 0x8048580 <unfinished ...>
getegid()                                                       = 2003
geteuid()                                                       = 2003

[...]
```

My question is: Why do `getegid()` returns `2003` whereas the executable's owner has uid 3003, and the suid bit is set?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out:

Nor gdb, ltrace or whatever external software starts the executable with `execve`, they run it with `execat`, which executes the code, within the current process, thus without changing any id.